# Android layout: combining LinearLayout and TableLaout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I would like to have a layout that looks like this (in landscape mode):
- on top 4 equally spaced button
- in middle: an EditText block and next to it on its right an ImageButton
- at the bottom a textview.

Here is the xml file that I used to implement this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dip"
>


<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/b1"
android:drawablePadding="5sp"
android:text="B1"></Button>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/b2"
android:drawablePadding="5sp"
android:text="B2"></Button>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/b3"
android:drawablePadding="7sp"
android:text="B3"></Button>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/b4"
android:drawablePadding="7sp"
android:text="B4"></Button>

</TableRow>   
</TableLayout> 

<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow>

<EditText 
android:id="@+id/entry"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_below="@id/e1"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  
/>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/search2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/i1" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
/>  

</TableRow>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/t2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="T2"/>

</TableLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

However, what I say is 4 buttons on top the way I want, and the rest (second row and third row) is not on the page (cannot be seen). I don't know where they have gone.
I appreciate any help for this.
Thanks,

TJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in parent LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I appreciate your help.

Comment: ...because the default orientation for a LinearLayout is horizontal.